# DISTINCT clause in main query and subquery

Tags: mysql

Below is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(di.device_token) FROM device_info di WHERE di.IMEI_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ud.device_id) FROM user_details ud WHERE ud.device_OS='android')
```

This query takes hell lot of time to execute because of the IN clause. I found using joins is the best way. Yet, I am unable to figure how to use `DISTINCT` on both the tables.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: use group by instead of distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query -

```
SELECT distinct (di.device_token) FROM device_info di,user_details
where di.IMEI_number in (user_details.ud.device_id)
and ud.device_OS='android';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT di.device_token FROM device_info di 
JOIN user_details ON user_details.ud.device_id = di.IMEI_number
WHERE ud.device_OS='android'
GROUP BY di.device_token
```

Comment: This too is taking lot of time to execute. Nearly 3 mins. Anything better would help a lot.

Comment: Can you share your tables definition with us? we need more information to see if there is a index problem.